# How do I register a tag in Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to add some css styles to a base html file in django version 2.2.0. However, I'm getting the following TemplateSyntaxError:

```
Invalid block tag on line 4: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

The css file named base.css exists in a directory named static. Here a print screen of the tree command.

```
.
├── blog
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── blog_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── Pipfile
├── static
│   └── css
│       └── base.css
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    └── home.html
```

And here is how I included the css in the base.html file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Django Blog</title>
        <link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Django blog</a></h1>
        </header>
        <div>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock content %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is how I have my static files directory inside the settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

My installed apps list inside settings.py looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
]
```

I tried changing `{% static 'css/base.css' %}` to `{% load static 'css/base.css' %}` but that produces this other error:

```
''css/base.css'' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
staticfiles
tz
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried changing `{% static 'css/base.css' %}` to `{% load static 'css/base.css' %}`

You should use two statements:

1. first you load the `static` library; and
2. next you can use the static template tag.

Like for example:

```
{% load static %}
<!-- ... -->
<head>
    <title>Django Blog</title>
    <link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

The `{% load static %}` is only used to load the template tags that are defined in the `static` app.

Note that, like the [documentation on static files [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) says, you will need to modify the `urls.py` file as well.

Comment: Thanks Willem! As soon as I loaded {% load static %} at the top of my base.html file it fixed it.